# SwipeRefreshLayout - the RecyclerView is not pulled down

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager` and when using `SwipeRefreshLayout` the `RecyclerView` is not pulled down. How to create the effect of having a gap between the *toolbar* and the *recyclerview* while refreshing?

**XML:**

```
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/gridView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

CODE:

```
swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
swipeLayout.setColorScheme(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright, android.R.color.holo_green_light, android.R.color.holo_orange_light, android.R.color.holo_red_light);

gridView = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.gridView);
gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 4, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
gridView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
gridView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
gridView.setHasFixedSize(false);
gridView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
```

Comment: What have u tried? may be paste your xml layout code?

Comment: I posted the code, but it is the simplest implementation with both of these two views. I think the problem resides in the GridLayoutManager, but I am not sure

Comment: does that help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25178329/recyclerview-and-swiperefreshlayout

Comment: no, because mine doesn't even move down. The refresh works, and the refresh view shows up, but on top of the grid, the grid does not move.

Comment: Try adding it inside linear vertical layout

Comment: doesn't change anything, and also the child of a swiperefreshlayout should be scrollable

Comment: the grid is not supposed to move either.. just the refresh icon would move down and up, for demo check this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nl8czoZtXVE :)

Comment: Is pull to refresh working and only pull down effect is not there. In that case  if you are using latest appcompat library it is not going to work. View can't be pull down in latest appcompat check gmail app

Comment: it's true. Didn't know this, should have checked the app. The usual behavior in all apps is to pull down, I guess Google does not agree, so I will stick with it. Thanks to you both

Comment: Yeah thats what u call Google's innovation :) I have added it as an answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is all okay, but the swipeRefreshLayout does not pull down the grid view but only itself, For the demo check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nl8czoZtXVE). You can however use other libraries like [Ulta-Pull-to-Refresh](https://github.com/liaohuqiu/android-Ultra-Pull-To-Refresh) to achieve the desired effect!